# Is absolute control possible with Wordpress

Tags: html

I understand that the different ways to build a website involve a pay-off between the amount of control you have versus the amount of time and effort you need to put in.

i.e. if a person builds a website from scratch, it is more time consuming, but they will be able to change any detail they like.

I am still learning about Wordpress.com and .org. As I understand it, you have more control over Wordpress.org (than .com), but the it is more complicated and hand-on as a result.

I have used Wordpress.com before and it was quick and easy to set up, but there were a few things within the theme that I wasn't easily able to change.

My question: is it possible to change every detail of a Wordpress.org and even a Wordpress.com site if you are prepared to dig down far enough and get dirty with the coding? In other words, can you have absolute control if you really want to, or is that only possible if you build the website yourself from scratch?

Thanks!

Comment: It's possible, `.org` more than `.com`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress is just a CMS written in PHP language (well, some Javascript, HTML, and CSS too). It means if you're building a self-hosted WordPress website (or, as you call it, WordPress.org) – you have absolute and total control and can do whatever you need. However, the possibilities are limited – by your own knowledge and experience, not the WordPress itself.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful. So can I infer that if one creates a Wordpress.com website, one doesn't have total control?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. WordPress.com is a hosted platform that has a lot of configuration options but it can't give you the total control.